# Joining key columns on an index

Tags: python, pandas, left-join

there are two DataFrame, left and right.

```
left = pd.DataFrame({'C': ['C0', 'C1'],
                     'D': ['D0', 'D1']},
                     index=['K0', 'K1'])

right = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
                      'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
                      'key': ['K0', 'K1', 'K0', 'K1']})
```

left:

[image]

right:

[image]

in the left frame keys are "k0, k1" that are index too, and are unique.
in the right frame keys are "k0, k1, k0, k1", they can occure any number of time.
the question is:
how join those frames that the result be:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First need reshape `right` by [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
right1 = right.pivot_table(index='key', 
                           columns=right.groupby('key').cumcount(),
                           aggfunc='first').sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
right1.columns = right1.columns.droplevel(0)
print (right1)
      0   0   1   1
key                
K0   A0  B0  A2  B2
K1   A1  B1  A3  B3
```

Another solution for `right1` is with [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) is with [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
g = right.groupby('key').cumcount()
right1 = right.groupby([right.key, g]).first().unstack().sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
right1.columns = right1.columns.droplevel(0)
print (right1)
      0   0   1   1
key                
K0   A0  B0  A2  B2
K1   A1  B1  A3  B3
```

And last use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with `inner` join or [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) too (how='inner' can be omit, because default parameter):

```
df = pd.concat([left, right1], axis=1, join='inner')
#assign default column names (0,1,2...)
df.columns = np.arange(len(df.columns))
df.index.name = None
print (df)
     0   1   2   3   4   5
K0  C0  D0  A0  B0  A2  B2
K1  C1  D1  A1  B1  A3  B3

df1 = pd.merge(left, right1, left_index=True, right_index=True)
#assign default column names (0,1,2...)
df1.columns = np.arange(len(df1.columns))
print (df1)
     0   1   2   3   4   5
K0  C0  D0  A0  B0  A2  B2
K1  C1  D1  A1  B1  A3  B3
```

Comment: nice thx. but in first line: "right1 = right.pivot_table(index='key'...)" there is a error: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. but other part work ok

Comment: Maybe version problem, try use `right1 = pd.pivot_table(right, index='key', columns=right.groupby('key').cumcount(),aggfunc='first')`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that puts all values for the keys into a list within a Series and then converts that to a DataFrame. It also faster for bigger data.

```
right_flat = right.set_index('key').groupby(level='key').apply(lambda x: x.values.flatten().tolist())
left_flat = pd.Series(left.T.to_dict('list'))
all_flat = left_flat + right_flat
df_final = pd.concat([pd.Series(v, name=idx) for idx, v in all_flat.iteritems()], axis=1).T
```

#### Speed Test

Make bigger data

```
right = right.sample(100000, replace=True)

%%timeit
right_flat = right.set_index('key').groupby(level='key').apply(lambda x: x.values.flatten().tolist())
left_flat = pd.Series(left.T.to_dict('list'))
all_flat = left_flat + right_flat
df_final = pd.concat([pd.Series(v, name=idx) for idx, v in all_flat.iteritems()], axis=1).T
```

100 loops, best of 3: 29.1 ms per loop

```
%%timeit
g = right.groupby('key').cumcount()
right1 = right.groupby([right.key, g]).first().unstack().sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
right1.columns = right1.columns.droplevel(0)
df = pd.concat([left, right1], axis=1, join='inner')
df.columns = np.arange(len(df.columns))
df.index.name = None
```

10 loops, best of 3: 96 ms per loop